# Data grid View ( winform ) not populating properly

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have two tables in my database `Department` and `Faculty`  . I am populating a datagridview for department list in my winform application . Both of my tables are following

**Department**

1. Sno (int)
2. Name (varchar(max))
3. Status (bit)
4. Faculty_id (int)

**Faculty**

1. Sno (int)
2. Name
3. Status

Now come to code i simply drag and drop a datagridview into my form and go to code behind file . In my form's load method i write following code

```
        var main = new SRMEntities();
        var departs = main.Department.ToList();
        DepartmentGrid.DataSource = departs;
```

now when my form load it show like this 
[image: Department Grid]

Look in faculty column its showing nothing and when we create department we store a faculty id into department . i want to show faculty name here .

Please let me know if you have any question .

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

My Database Diagram

[image: Database]

Comment: You need to use `join` query on faculty table with faculty_id..

Comment: Sir how can i use that . I am using Entity Framework

Comment: How the `Faculty_id` is related with `Faculty` table..?

Comment: This is one-to-many relation . One faculty have many departments

Comment: So the primary key of `Faculty` table must exist in the `Department` table as a foreign key..so where it is?

Comment: i already did what you are saying , but i was asking that every department which is showing in department grid has faculty_id , i want to get that faculty name by id and want to show that name in faculty column

Comment: @Smartboy try my answer below.

Comment: @BizApps :-( its not working i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is correct join:

```
var main = new SRMEntities();
var query = from f in main.Faculty
            join d in main.Department on f.Sno equals d.Faculty.Sno
            select new { d.Sno, d.Name, d.Status, Faculty = f.Name };

DepartmentGrid.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: @smartboy isn't column `Faculty_id` holds faculty FK in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is dependent on your query............ Your query should contain both the tables with Join.

```
var main = new SRMEntities();
var departs = main.Department.ToList();
DepartmentGrid.DataSource = departs;
```

Please check the above code **"main.Department.ToList();"** is returning only Departments and your assigning the **"departs"** to your grid.

Whether **"main.Department"** contains the **"Faculty"** table info?

By looking at your code i am guessing you have a seperate items like below

```
1.main.Department
2.main.Faculty
```

Comment: So , what you mean should i assign datasource 2 times one time for departs and one time for faculty ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your tables

something like:

```
var main = new SRMEntities();

    var source = (from d in main.Department
                 join f in main.Faculty on d.Faculty.Sno=f.Sno
                 select new
                 {
                  Sno = d.Sno ,
                  Name = d.Name,
                  Status = d.Status, 
                  Faculty = f.Name
                 }
                 );   

    DepartmentGrid.DataSource = source.ToList();
```

Regards

Comment: your code is not compiling i think there are some mistakes , please see my edit i attached my db diagram in which u will see the actual names